# sqlplus - command line select statement doesn't use login.sql settings

Tags: sql, shell, authentication, sqlplus

I have an sh script containing this:

```
sqlplus -S $JDBC_URL <<EOF
$1;
EOF
```

That works fine. However, it doesn't pick my formatting preferences from login.sql. Those settings work fine when I start SQL Plus in interactive mode.

Does anyone know how to make my script read login.sql? Is there some other file perhaps?

Comment: Why would you want formatting preferences for something which one would expect to be a batch process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version of `sqlplus` you are using and the operating system, you likely need to set and export the `ORACLE_PATH` (linux) or `SQLPATH` (windows) environment variable to include the directory that contains `login.sql`.

I just found that past version used to look in the present-working-directory but that was not happening on the linux server I was working on.  Setting `SQLPATH` did not work either because it is used in windows; setting `ORACLE_PATH` did work.

[Attribution for this information](http://dbaparadise.com/2017/08/how-to-make-login-sql-work-again-in-12-2-and-11-2-0-4/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use glogin.sql instead - see [OraFAQ on SQL Plus](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aPlus_FAQ)